# Where should I upload code which is too long to get posted?

Tags: support, code, answer-length

I put a bounty on another question and someone [answered](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/323806/66769), but the answer contains a .zip file, because Stack Exchange has a limit on the maximum post length and the code exceeds that.

**Problem**: The .zip file is hosted on the author's own website, and that website might not be available anymore one day, and an important part of the answer will be lost.

How should I deal with the situation? Ask the answer author to upload their code on GitHub?

Comment: If it requires that much code the question is probably too broad

Comment: @Luuklag, where to ask questions which are too broad? Is there a better platform than stackoverflow for complex questions?

Comment: Duplicate contains useful answers for you.

Comment: @Black better in what way? There are alternatives, it's hard to judge if better or not. Quora is one, another one is Reddit which has programming categories as well.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask, ok so stackoverflow is only for trivial questions?

Comment: @Black not at all. It's for questions which focus on a specific problem/issue.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask, but thats exactly what my question does. It asks about a specific problem.

Comment: @Black fair enough, so you can ignore the first comment if that's really true. Still, SO won't remove the post length limit just for the very rare cases where huge amount of code is required, so it's not really relevant. There are good and free hosts for pure text like pastebin.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask, There is a link in the question, so you can judge yourself. I will just ask the answer author to upload the code to github or I will do it and edit his answer.

Comment: @Black yes, that can work.

Comment: The question is on Magento, not SO.

Comment: @Mast, Sorry, I mean stackexchange, not stackoverflow

Comment: @Mast if you mean what's in the question itself it's my bad, sorry. I edited it, and fixed now.